# If set $A_n$ converges to $A$ in $L^1$, then is it also true for the $r$-neighborhood?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, graph-theory

Let $A$ be a bounded simply connected set in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and $A^r$ denote the $r$-neighborhood of $A$, that is, $A^r:=\{x: d(x,A) \le r\}$. Suppose there exists $A_n \rightarrow A$ in $L^1$, that is, $|A \Delta A_n| \rightarrow 0$, then prove $A_n^r \rightarrow A^r$ in $L^1$.

It seems to be very intuitive based on the picture, but strangely I've no idea how to make a rigorous proof. Any comments will be really appreciated.

---

Thanks to the answer provided by @zhw, I realized I had asked a trivial question. Later I asked another question here [On the $r$-neighborhood of a set in $\mathbb{R}^2$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1872317/on-the-r-neighborhood-of-a-set-in-mathbbr2) to fully make sense of the background and my concern.

Comment: Are the $A_n$ just measurable, or are they simply connected too?

Comment: Let's assume all the sets are measurable and simply connected, although I think the simply connectedness assumption can be removed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, here's a counterexample: Let $A = D(0,1),$ and $A_n = D(0,1) \cup \{(x,y): |y| < (e^{-x^2}) /n\}.$ Then $A_n \to A$ in $L^1$ (in your sense), but $|A_n^r| = \infty$ for every $r$ and $n.$

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean to ask a trivial question. The picture in this answer is not what in my mind. I want to truly understand what if $A_n$ is also bounded, or even $d(A_n, A) \rightarrow 0$ where $d$ is the Hausforff distance function?

Comment: Sorry for my bad question.

Comment: I'll accept this answer and open up a different question which there are more assumptions. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1872317/on-the-r-neighborhood-of-a-set-in-mathbbr2

Comment: Would the person who downvoted care to explain?