# On the $r$-neighborhood of a set in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, geometric-measure-theory

> Suppose $A$ is a simply connected open set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with rectifiable Jordan boundary. Let $\gamma:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ be the parametrization of $\partial A$. Let $A^r$ denote the $r$-neighborhood of $A$, that is, $A^r:=\{x: d(x,A) \le r\}$. Let $0=t_0<t_1< \cdots <t_n=1$ be the partition of $[0,1]$ such that $P(A_n) \rightarrow P(A)$ where $P$ is the perimeter function and $A_n$ is the polygon with verticies $\gamma(t_i), i=1,2,...n$. The construction of $A_n$ can be realized since $\partial A$ is rectifiable and $P(A)=sup_{0=t_0<t_1< \cdots <t_n=1} \sum_{I=1}^{n} |\gamma(t_i)-\gamma(t_{i-1})|$. We can also make sure $A_n \Delta A \subset (\partial A)^{\frac{1}{n}}$ and thus $A_n \rightarrow A$ in $L^1$.

My question is, based on the previous construction, can we conclude $A_n^r \rightarrow A^r$ in $L^1$ and $P(A_n^r) \rightarrow P(A^r)$? If one of them is true then I will be very happy. However even if the picture is very intuitive, I cannot come up with a rigorous proof. Especially I think the first claim is so intuitive, but strangely I still have no idea how to give a rigorous proof.

The question comes from my random doodling in a geometric measure theory class. By the way, I have proved $P(A^r) \le P(A)+2\pi r$ for any simply connected polygon $A$ and any $r>0$.

Any comments or ideas will be really appreciated.

Comment: How do you choose the approximating sequence $A_n$? Requiring only that $P(A_n)\to P(A)$ does not suffice to deduce the convergence $P(A_n^r)\to P(A^r)$: take $A$ as two squares of side 1, one on top of the other but separated by a small distance $r_0$, and $r=r_0/2$. Then $A_r$ does not have boundary between the squares, but an approximating sequence can have boundary of total length 2 in between. You can obtain a connected counterexample connecting the squares from the other sides. You can also make countably many smaller copies to have arbitrarily small $r$ that fail